# How to set parameter by getting text from textarea in MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web, parameters, bootstrap-modal

I want to make an approve and reject button in foreach loop.

Approve button use only item's ID. So I have no problem.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Approve", "Home", new {page = "leave/st/approve/", id = @item.ID, actionName ="LeaveRequests"})'">Approve</button>
```

But in reject button, I have to take explanation from text area to send web service.

[image]

So I added a bootstrap modal;

```
  <button type="button" id="btnReject" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop-@item.ID">Rejet</button>
```

And this is my modal ;

```
  <!-- Modal --><div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop-@item.ID" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header"><h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Red İşlemi</h5><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button></div><div class="modal-body">
                                <label for="input" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Explanation .. </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">

                                    @*I want to get this explanation*@
                                    <textarea id="explanation" class="form-control" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>


                                @*THIS URL ACTION*@
                                <a class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("Reject", "Home", new {page="leave/st/reject/",id=@item.ID,
                                                                actionName = "LeaveRequests", exp= ? })" id="lnk">OK</a>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have to get value from explanation text area and add to url action in modal.

How can I get textarea value in url action ?

My view form is here ;

```
        <form method="post">
        <section class="section">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">@item.NameSurname - @item.Section</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">@item.StartDate / @item.EndDate</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">@item.Days gün @item.Hours saat</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">@item.Type @item.PriceState</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">@item.Expression</h6>
                                <p class="card-text">@item.CompExplain</p>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Approve", "Home", new {page = "leave/st/approve/", id = @item.ID, actionName ="LeaveRequests"})'">Approve</button>
                                <button type="button" id="btnReject" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop-@item.ID">Reject</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal --><div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop-@item.ID" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header"><h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Red İşlemi</h5><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button></div><div class="modal-body">
                                        <label for="input" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Explanation..</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">

                                            @*I want to get this explanation*@
                                            <textarea id="explanation" class="form-control" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">İptal</button>


                                        @*THIS URL ACTION*@
                                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("Reject", "Home", new {page="leave/st/reject/",id=@item.ID,
                                                                        actionName = "LeaveRequests", exp= ? })" id="lnk">OK</a>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should post your question with "actual" code. if you are using jQuery you can use JS to pull the value from the textarea or any input by using its id:

```
<script>
    $('#btnReject').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: @Url.Action("Reject", "Home", {page="leave/st/reject/", id=@item.ID, actionName = "LeaveRequests"}) + '?exp=' + $("#explanation").val()
            type: 'POST',
            // ... other ajax options ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

otherwise you can use `form` element and use "submit" buttons to submit values to form action. You may have to adapt this code to your project.

```
    <form method="get" action="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")" >
       @Html.Textbox("toPay")
       <input type="submit" value="Pay"/>
    </form>
```

I would suggest using JS to pull this off.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I added my view code to question. And I will try to add JS to my project.